# Hamiltonian of a particle in magnetic field squared

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin, hamiltonian

I'm trying to follow Tong lectures about Gauge Theories, but I think I'm doing some really stupid mistake.

At one point he takes the Hamiltonian for a spin $1/2$ particle in a potential as the usual
\begin{equation*}
H=(\mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A})\cdot\mathbf{\sigma}
\end{equation*}
Where $\mathbf{p}$ is the momentum, $\mathbf{A}$ the vector potential and $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is the vector of the Pauli matrices.
Now he squares the result, using $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\delta_{ij}+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$ and he finds
\begin{equation*}
H^2=(\mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A})^2-2e\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{S}
\end{equation*}
with $\mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\sigma}$ the spin operator.

I tried to reproduce this calculation, but I think I'm missing something. I write $H^2$ as
\begin{align*}
H^2&=(p_i-eA_i)\sigma_i(p_j-eA_j)\sigma_j=\\
&=(p_i-eA_i)(p_j-eA_j)(\delta_{ij}+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k)=\\
&=(\mathbf{p}-e\mathbf{A})^2+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k(p_i-eA_i)(p_j-eA_j)
\end{align*}
The last term seems to be the product of an antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon_{ijk}$ in $ij$ times a symmetric part, and this should go to zero.

What am I missing? How do I recover the $-2e\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{S}$ term?

Comment: You may have to use the position representation of the momentum operator $p_j \rightarrow  - i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$.

Comment: Do not forget, that $p$ is a operator, and it doesn't actually commute with $A$

Comment: Ohh, right, that's what I was missing. Thanks a lot

Comment: You might need also the symmetric Coulomb vector potential $\mathbf{A}=1/2( \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{B})$ if I rememb. correctly.

Comment: What is the answer? Can someone post the full derivation?